# Change ulimit in Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Any possibility to change the ulimit value in docker container ?.

I pull down the centos docker image and start the container from it. But I couldn't increase the ulimit value inside the container. It show "Operation  not permitted".

Yes, I know docker doesn't have permission to do so. Searched in google, they reported to `run --ulimit` option when deploying docker container. But that doesn't work for me.

```
docker run -d  --ulimit nofile=8000:16000 * --expose=80  --expose=443 centos:centos6 nginx -g 'daemon off;'
flag provided but not defined: --ulimit
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The `--ulimit` option was added in docker 1.6 (see the related pull-request here: https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9437).

I you're using an older version of docker, you won't be able to use this feature, in which case you should update to the current docker version

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [commit 3f39050](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/3f39050637d454e9ee8075153a917c8bfccb5bae), the option ulimit is one introduced in Docker 1.6.0+.

If the option is not recognized, it might be because docker version does not return 1.60+.